# Why are my columns not aligned when attempting to run it?

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to get the average salary of each job position, but instead I kept getting the same output of it not aligned with each other.

How do I fix it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         h.jobCode "Job",
         j.jobDesc "Job Description", 
         AVG(salary) "Salary"
     FROM 
         jobHistory h
     FULL JOIN 
         job j ON h.jobCode = j.jobDesc
     GROUP BY 
         (h.jobCode),(j.jobDesc)
     ORDER BY 3);
```

Here is the code I'm doing, but the output is like this:

[image]

Comment: SQL is a query language. It has nothing to do with layout of the results, that's up to the *client*. There doesn't seem to be any problem either - `Accountant` etc start at the left of the `Job Description` column. The JOIN condition `h.jobCode=j.jobDesc` won't return any matches if the code and description are like the ones in the image, so the results will include all History rows with a `NULL` for Job Description and all Job rows with a NULL for `Job`

Comment: With that means the output of my column allignment doesn't matter? or is there anyway i could allign the two column? thank you sir

Comment: There is no alignment to speak off. There are three columns. The data appear in the correct column. The real problem is that the query is wrong and joining on the wrong columns, not any alignment.